# How to migrate AWS SES email templates between regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, templates, amazon-ses

I have several (30+) AWS SES email templates in one region and lately I have to use an other region for an other client and I want to migrate all of my templates to the new region. The CLI is not so helpful because you can only list the names of the templates not the contents.

Comment: Hi, there is actually a service out there, offering exactly this funtionality. No CLI or anything needed. https://semplates.io

Comment: I built engagespot.co so templates can be vendor-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The [GetTemplate Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetTemplate.html) *"Displays the template object (which includes the Subject line, HTML part and text part) for the template you specify."*

Python SDK example:

```py
session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
ses = session.client('ses')

# create some dummy templates
for i in range(3):
  ses.create_template(Template={
    "TemplateName": f'Template{i}',
    'HtmlPart': '<body></body>',
    'SubjectPart': 'hello',
    'TextPart': 'hello'
  })

# download them
templates = [ses.get_template(TemplateName=m['Name']) for m in ses.list_templates()['TemplatesMetadata']]

print(templates[0]['Template'])
# --> {'TemplateName': 'Template2', 'SubjectPart': 'hello', 'TextPart': 'hello', 'HtmlPart': '<body></body>'}
```